# What is the meaning of "Clients MUST NOT multiplex XMPP streams over the same WebSocket" (from RFC 7395 § 3.4)?

Tags: websocket, xmpp, rfc

While I was reading the [RFC 7395](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7395/?include_text=1). I read this statement

From **Section 3.4.  Stream Initiation** *Page 6*

> Clients MUST NOT multiplex XMPP streams over the same WebSocket.

I have questions

What is multiplex XMPP streams?

Why Clients MUST NOT multiplex XMPP streams over the same WebSocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you must not use multiple XMPP streams over the same WebSocket. If this was allowed then you could use 2 or more streams over the same WebSocket, e.g. allowing you to authenticate and use 2 or more XMPP sessions over the same WebSocket.